# Can you style a td based on the th relationship?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say I have a th like so...

```
<th>
  <div class="text-left field-sorting " rel="local_inventory"> Local inventory </div>
</th>
<th>
  <div class="text-left field-sorting " rel="something else1"> Something Else1 </div>
</th>
<th>
  <div class="text-left field-sorting " rel="something else2"> Something Else2 </div>
</th>
```

and I want the associating td...

```
<td>4</td>
<td>0</td>
<td></td>
```

to have some sort of style without adding a class, is it possible based on if value exists (if number greater than 0 and not empty) to style this td? I would use jQuery to apply CSS. Otherwise I would hack into the PHP script that automates this data grid. I know it is possible to access the th, so I guess my question is how to use that, to access the related td even if the td does not have anything unique other than being in the same column.

Comment: just to be clear, you are trying to find all `td` elements in the same column as a given `th`?

Comment: Are you trying to access all `td`'s within the given column, or are you only trying to access `td`'s in the column that also have `width=5%`?

Comment: Just add a class. The performance hit for updating the style with jQuery is not worth it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this assuming they are both in the same table. Setting the width on the header cell should also set the width on all other cells in that column

Comment: @MichaelPeterson forget the width, they are all the same. All of the td's within a given column, then select only ones with data.

Comment: If you're trying to select only non-empty `td`'s within a given column, you can use the css `:not` and `:empty` selectors: `td:not(:empty)` prefacing it with a selector for the specific column.

Comment: @Mathletics The PHP handles 20 tables, so that could be heavier for those I don't use it for and I have page limits. So I wanted to point out our stock on hand for this table.

Comment: You think an HTML class is "heavier" than updating CSS with jQuery? :-/

Comment: Hmm, no mention of `<col>` and `<colgroup>` ...

Comment: @Mathletics The workload of taking the automation might be more work, because the script is designed to create the columns, CRUD and other data based on the MySQL table. I did not want to go that route, but will consider if this does not work. I believe you, but wanted to see if an easy plug for something like this in CSS. Also, it is a library that has not been altered and wanted to keep it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the `.filter` method here?

```
$('td').filter(function(){
  var text = $.trim($(this).text());
  return text.length && +text > 0;
}).addClass('greater-than-zero');
```

Here's a quick little demo: http://jsbin.com/abovow/1/edit

---

I understand the question better now. How about this?

```
$('td, th').addClass(function(idx){
 return 'col-' + ( $(this).index() + 1 );
});
```

With a demo: http://jsbin.com/abovow/4/edit

Comment: All of my td fields would then be altered. I simply want to bind the td to the th. This is way too global for that task.

Comment: I have not got it working, but got enough to see it will work as I asked. Very good stuff!, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nth-child` selector to target the td. This would style all the corresponding `td's` for the `th` in the same column.

Otherwise I don't think you can write up a selector based on `th` condition atleast using `CSS` .

Using jQUery or adding a class should better suit your needs in that case.

```
tr td:nth-child(2) { // Targets the 2nd td inside each tr
    // Some style
}
```

Comment: `rowspan` throws a wrench in this. The OP didn't mention that though, so this might be good enough